# Trying to run Program in Ecplise as a class × 259989

Tags: java

I am a newbie in the Java world and this is among my first programs (Hello World, obviously!). The problem is when I try to run this program as a class from the menu with a play icon on it, a blank window shows up with no "Hello World" on it (just white colour filling the window). At the bottom border of this window there is a black thick line. But when I run this program as an applet from the same menu everything is okay and the "Hello World" shows at the right position and everything is fine. But how can I make the program run regularly as a class???

This is my code...

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class HelloProgram extends GraphicsProgram {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void run() {
        GLabel label = new GLabel("hello, world", 100, 75);
        label.setFont("SansSerif-36");
        label.setColor(Color.RED);
        add(label);
    }

}
```

Comment: What does it mean to "run regularly as a class"?

Comment: If you need to run as class, you should have main method in that class (or) open the class where you have run method and click run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea about acm, but looked in this page: http://jtf.acm.org/tutorial/Introduction.html

As you see there GraphicsProgram is a subclass of JApplet and because of that it's supposed to be run as applet, not desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will be a separate class, but you will be able to run your program from this one. Please let me know if you are confused.

```
public class Runner{
   public static void main(String[] args){
   HelloProgram p = new HelloProgram();
   p.run();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with publ1c_stat1c, your program is missing the "main" method for it to be considered a standalone application.

1. Create an instance of your application

   `HelloProgram hello = new HelloProgram();`
2. call the run method of the instance

   `hello.run();`

the main method doesn't have to be in a different class, try adding below codes in-between "run method" and "`private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;`"

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    HelloProgram hello = new HelloProgram();
    hello.run();
}
```

Comment: I've done this but still it only works as an applet. Thanks :)